# I get an error when I try to execute my Powershell script in C#. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand cmd1 = new PSCommand();

 cmd1.AddCommand("Grant-CsTenantDialPlan")
.AddParameter("Identity", "xxxx.yyyy@xxxxx.com.tr")
.AddParameter("PolicyName", "DialPlan-GMMA");

 ps.Commands = cmd1;
 ps.Invoke();
```

I'm not sending the PolicyName parameter empty. But why am I still getting the error?

Stack Trace:

at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()
at ConnectTeams.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\ConnectTeams\ConnectTeams\Program.cs:line 120

Comment: We can't guess without the actual full exception text. That tells you where the error occurred, which method threw it, whether there was an inner exception and which chain of calls caused this. You can easily get the full exception text with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup while debugging. Right now we don't even know if that's the code that throws or some other code right after `Invoke()`

Comment: BTW this question will probably be closed as a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and How do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) unless you post something that shows that eg the problem was raised inside `Grant-CsTenantDialPlan`. Perhaps there's no Skype installed on the machine?

Comment: I updated my question, added a stack trace. I want to run the command Grant-CsOnlineTenantDialPlan in Microsoft Teams. I can connect to Microsoft Teams, no problem. But I am getting an error in this command and other commands with PolicyName parameter.  @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Post the *full* exception text, not just the stack trace. Teams and Skype For Business are two completely different products. Skype For Business isn't even Skype, it's the Microsoft Lync/Microsoft Communicator of the 2010s that was renamed `Skype For Business` when Skype was acquired. Teams is a replacement for that and MS is mothballing it. Don't assume it's installed